# How to tune this query when updating 4 million records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance

I have this query to set the date to far far in the future. The table has 4 million records. And the query is really straight forward. But the query took almost 3 min to run.

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET to_date = STR_TO_DATE('31-01-3000','%d-%m-%Y') 
WHERE to_date IS NULL;
```

There's no INDEX on this column.

How can I tune this query or MySQL itself? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you opposed to adding an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest solution not involving an index (and in fact, the fastest solution PERIOD), would be to make the column default to '31-01-3000', which means you'll never have to update it.  Note that the initial ALTER may take quite a few minutes, though, considering you're running it on such a large table.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
CHANGE COLUMN `to_date` `to_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '3000-01-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate SELECT to get the indexes for those records, and then UPDATE based on the index.  And store the calculation ahead of time, using a user-defined variable.

```
SET @newDate = STR_TO_DATE('31-01-3000','%d-%m-%Y')
UPDATE yourTable 
SET to_date = @newDate
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM yourTable WHERE to_date IS NULL
)
```

Also, if possible, consider programming around this requirement.  My own preference is to have end-dates that are not set to be NULL, and then have queries smart enough to substitute tomorrow for NULL when querying the end-date.